# I did not receive a notification for a question I followed that was edited after I was following it

Tags: bug, notifications, follow-posts

Just as the title states:

I did not receive a notification for a question I followed that was edited.

Being [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63548047/perform-calculating-on-each-result-of-a-mysql-search) on Stack Overflow.

I did receive a notification for the OP posting a comment under a comment I left in their question but not for the post that they edited.

Edit: I was following the question before it was edited.

Comment: When did you start following that question. After the first edit was made?

Comment: @rene I made an edit. I was following it before the edit. Maybe there wasn't enough time between my following it and their edit?

Comment: Okay, weird. As the last edits were only a tag and a title edit I assumed maybe only edits of the body of the post would notify followers. I didn't find confirmation that this is how it is supposed to work but it was something that stood out in the timeline so it was worth asking to confirm the exact timings.

Comment: @rene Yes, I found it rather odd myself and it's the first time this happens to me. I waited to ask the question to see if it would appear a bit later, giving it the benefit of the doubt. But alas, it didn't and it doesn't show up in my recent inbox messages. Edit: I believe I clicked the "follow" button after I posted [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63548047/perform-calculating-on-each-result-of-a-mysql-search#comment112371481_63548047) about it.

Comment: @rene I don't mean to tie up comments, but I tried to see if there was a timestamp for when I followed the question and trying to compare that with when the question was edited and it doesn't show it. It'd be nice to have that as an added feature. I almost made an edit to my post that contained the date/time I started following it. I guess such a feature would probably be too hard on the system.

Comment: @rene That I know. It shows when it was edited. What I meant by my above comment was that, it'd be nice to know when I started following the question, that way there would have been something to compare with.

Comment: I don't get _any_ notifications after I've elected to follow a question. I don't understand what following is supposed to do.

Comment: Same happened to me, I was not notified about a title-only edit